# How do you extract only the date from a python datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, tokenize

I have a dataframe in python. One of its columns is labelled `time`, which is a timestamp. Using the following code, I have converted the timestamp to `datetime`:

```
milestone['datetime'] = milestone.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x['time']), axis = 1)
```

Now I want to separate (tokenize) date and time and have two different columns like `milestone['only_date']` and `milestone['only_time']`. How do I do this?

Comment: As in `datetime.date()` and `datetime.time()`?

Comment: @dhke Sorry, duplicate comment. Internet is running slow here. I voted for your dupe target.

Comment: How do I apply datetime.date() and datetime.time() to the whole series

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No worries, conflict resolution is impossible in distributed systems without an arbiter ;-)

Comment: No, this question is not a duplicate for the question posted above. My question is different. I have dates in the form of timestamps. These dates are stored in a pandas dataframe. Using the code given above, I am adding a new column in the dataframe. This new column uses the  fromtimestamp function of datetime to convert the time stamp to datetime. I now want to separate this datetime into date and time and save it into two new columns of the dataframe.

Comment: milestone['date'] = milestone['datetime'].map(pd.Timestamp.date)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `date` and `time` methods of the `datetime` class to do so:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> only_date, only_time = d.date(), d.time()
>>> only_date
datetime.date(2015, 11, 20)
>>> only_time
datetime.time(20, 39, 13, 105773)
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) is the `datetime` documentation.

Applied to your example, it can give something like this:

```
>>> milestone["only_date"] = [d.date() for d in milestone["datetime"]]
>>> milestone["only_time"] = [d.time() for d in milestone["datetime"]]
```

Comment: I can do this. but I have datetime as a column in my DataFrame. I have to tokenize it into date and time.

Comment: This code works. Thanks :)>>> milestone["only_date"] = [d.date() for d in milestone["datetime"]]
>>> milestone["only_time"] = [d.time() for d in milestone["datetime"]]